# output streams buffered output streams appending

Tags: java

I know how to create / write/ close buffered output stream. How do I reopen the stream and append data to end of the file.

Answer (score 4):

You can't *reopen* a stream... but you can create a *new* stream which will append:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

See the constructor list for [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) for the various options.

(Of course, you can then wrap that `FileOutputStream` with a `BufferedOutputStream`.)